# Condition does not work?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

when this condition came true it does not take the following actions
what did I make wrong !?

```
int main(){
printf("Press t/T for Tan x\nPress s/S for Sin x\nPressc/C for Cos x\n\nPress * for exit the program..");
scanf("%c",&choice);


    if(choice==s||choice==S){
        printf("Enter....etc");
        ......etc
```

this condition does not work with me at all
plz help

Comment: What is the **type** of `choice`?

Comment: This looks like `choice`, `s` and `S` are all variables. Where are they declared? Can you post an example that will compile?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer due to incomplete code. Please post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `choice` before you can use it:

```
char choice;
```

Then your conditional should be as follows:

```
if(choice=='s'||choice=='S')
```

`choice` is of type `char` so you will need to compare it to `char`'s. you can make a char literal easily using single quotations.

Answer (score 0):

As you are comparing `char` (at least it looks like), make sure they are in `''`

```
 if(choice=='s'||choice=='S'){
```

Comment: Shouldn't he use strcmp?

Comment: If type is string or char* or char array. For single char '=' is enough. @ClaudioCortese

Answer (score 0):

First, declare `choice` by adding the following statement at the beginning

```
int choice;
```

Then, change

```
if(choice==s||choice==S){
```

to

```
if(choice == 's' || choice == 'S'){
```

This is because `s` and `S` are identifiers, which can be the name of a variable or function, while `'s'` and `'S'` are character constants, which stands for `int`s whose value is the ascii value of the embraced character. For example, `s` is identical to 115, and `S` is identical to 83. You should use character constants because characters are stored as integer values in C.

BTW, `scanf(" %c", &choice);` seems to be better, because it can discard all annoying whitespace characters (if any) like `'\n'`. Using `scanf("%c", &choice);` won't cause problems in this case, but you'd better add that leading space if you want to input `s` multi times.